# Proposed Tag: 'derivation'

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

Would a 'derivations' tag be useful?  i.e. for questions asking about the derivation of established laws and equations.  In my experience, understanding derivations (at least of college-level physics material) can be extremely useful and insightful---often far better than memorizing a result.  A 'derivations' tag might be good to give these types of questions/answers more attention, and let people especially fond-of/expert-at them find them more easily.

My primary concern with such a tag might be that [it's too meta](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6031/8521).  Being a derivation, however, does directly address the content of the question itself and the relevant skills/material required to address it.

An additional modifier might be good to distinguish "derivation" as in, 're-deriving an equation'; as apposed to derivative 'derivation', as in an anti-integral.  Especially for non-native english speakers, this could be an issue.

[This post ("Rigorous treatment of blackbody radiation")](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/304413/rigorous-treatment-of-blackbody-radiation), for example, might be a good candidate for such a tag.

Comment: [More on meta tags](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)

Comment: @rob thanks for pointing that out, I've added some discussion about that in the below answer.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks to @rob for linking to [Atwood's Meta-Tag post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) (which I somehow always forget about...).  To quote:

> [1] The reason meta-tags are a problem is that they do not describe the content of the question. They describe some other aspect of the question, like the author's skill level[...]
>
> [2] Meta-tags are actually [...] dependent tags. These are tags that don't say anything by themselves - you can't tell what the question is about unless they're paired with some other tag[...].

Re [1]: I'd argue that 'derivation' is *not* consistent with [1] in that, like the much discussed 'homework' tag, it *does* describe the content of the question itself, and seeing the 'derivation' tag would indeed provide a keyword/description of the content of the question.

Re [2]: I think [2] *does* apply, but only marginally.  A 'thermal-physics' could go-it-alone, and be perfectly sufficient, while a 'derivation' tag would be missing the actual physical content of the question.  But, that is to say 'derivation' would not be a *complete* description tag, much like ['computational-physics'](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computational-physics), ['forces'](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/forces), or ['mathematical-physics'](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematical-physics).  So I personally don't think [2] is a deal-breaker.  Comments welcome

Comment: I think when Jeff writes about "content of the question", he means to exclude things like "derivation" or "homework". He's talking about the _topics_ involved in the question. The idea is that there will be people with expertise in a tag area, and they can use the tags as a way to identify which questions they're likely to be able to answer. E.g. it's quite reasonable that someone might specialize in, or have particular expertise in, thermal/computational/mathematical physics, or force problems (think of a student). That's not likely to be the case with derivations.